# Xcode 9 rebuilding issue?

Tags: ios11, swift4, xcode9, building

I updated my Xcode to Xcode 9 and working on swift 4, but my project get build again and again as I minorly change my code. Now I am quite new to swift so i don't know that this is due to swift or Xcode 9 and how to stop this, because it makes working process very slow. any help ?

Comment: I haven't dug into xcode 9 yet,  I still do alot in 8.2.  But I can say that i have been around on and off all day and see tons of problems pop up with xcode9.  I usually wait until all that stuff goes away.  If you are new, learn some older stuff and come back to it when all these bugs get worked out.  Just a suggestion.  You can easily pick up changes once you learn it

Comment: But you don't have to.  You certainly can contribute to this as you are with the problems.  I just think for new people it gets overwhelming

Answer (score 2):

I also faced such issue in my recent project. Try the following

```
1. Main StoryBoard - Editor - Disable "Automatic Refresh Views"
2. Go to Preferences -> General and disable Show Live Issues.
3. Comment any @IBDesignables used in your project
```

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issue. Turning off "Parallelize Build" option in "Edit Scheme / Build / Build" helped.